# How to disable admob in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

I added admob to my libgdx project without any problem but How can I disable admob in game. I have 2 screen(MainMenu and PlayScreen) and I want to ads  to be shown only at MainMenu.

I have found an article about conntrolling ads in libgdx but the problem is this article is for Desktop not Android.

<strike>https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AdMobInLibgdx</strike> (Note: question arises in part from using  deprecated document, newer version available at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx)

Comment: The article is for all implementations! its actually interfacing between the plattforms and everything you need to know does stand there. It even shows you how to set up admob in android and how to call it inside of the core project. Read the article and you can do it. Also if there stand we moved the wiki to git you meight should look at the new wiki instead of the old one. -1 for not reading the article

Comment: @BennX - please provide your solution of the newer document in a comment or answer, rather than by editing the question.  Yes, the poster should have followed the new link, but apparently their not having done so is the basis of the question - so editing the question to change the document they found for the one they didn't rather nullifies the question asked.

Comment: @ChrisStratton i'm sorry and added the link to the new wiki

Comment: Your intention was good, let's see if this way preserves the question while not leading future readers to accidentally visit the old version, as you had presumably hoped to prevent.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [#control at the new wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx). There are 2 Final static values inside of your **Android Project**:

```
public class HelloWorldAndroid extends AndroidApplication {

private final int SHOW_ADS = 1;
private final int HIDE_ADS = 0;

protected Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what) {
            case SHOW_ADS:
            {
                adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //change to visible
                break;
            }
            case HIDE_ADS:
            {
                adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);//change to not visible
                // you should also disable the ad fetching here!
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

So if you call the method: (which is parsed as interface to the core project)

```
public interface IActivityRequestHandler {
   public void showAds(boolean show);
}

public class HelloWorldAndroid extends AndroidApplication implements IActivityRequestHandler  {

...

    // This is the callback that posts a message for the handler
    @Override
    public void showAds(boolean show) {
       handler.sendEmptyMessage(show ? SHOW_ADS : HIDE_ADS);
    }
```

it sends an message to the handler which activates or disable the admob. The interface for `showAds` is passed to the core project so you can hold an reference to it and use it. To see how this works take a look at the article of interfacing [plattformspec code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code).

Just to show this here:

```
View gameView = initializeForView(new HelloWorld(this), false); // and "this" is the mainclass of the android project which implements the IActivityRequestHandler interface shown above
//the HelloWorld(this) is the core project where you now can save the `IActivityRequestHandler` as referance and call the showAds(bool)
```

*But in the end if you would have read the aticle you should have know this all.*